# Unable to interpolate values in Serverless Framework for AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

I'm trying to organize this serverless YML file, but getting failures.I've scanned their docs for understanding how to interpolate via file substitution and I just can't figure it out:

I've read all these:

- https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-properties-in-other-files
- https://forum.serverless.com/t/split-up-include-reference-serverless-yml-file/3747
- https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-stack-demo-api/blob/master/serverless.yml#L128-L137

#### ERRORS

```
 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
 The CloudFormation template is invalid: [/Resources/IamRoleLambdaExecution/Type/Policies/0/PolicyDocument/Statement/2] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

`Serverless.yaml`

```
service: newsletter

frameworkVersion: '2'

plugins:
  - serverless-bundle

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  memorySize: 256
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: us-west-2
  iamRoleStatements:
    - ${file(resources/iam/UsersSubscriptionTable.yml):UsersSubscriptionTableIAM}

resources:
  - ${file(/resources/dynamo/UsersSubscriptionTable.yml):UsersSubscriptionTable}

functions:
  createEmailEntry:
    handler: src/Email.addUser
    events:
      - http:
          method: POST
          path: /subscribe
  removeEmailEntry:
    handler: src/Email.removeUser
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: /unsubscribe

# Not recommended for production-use
custom:
  bundle:
    linting: false
```

`resources/iam/UsersSubscriptionTable.yml`

```
Resources:
  UsersSubscriptionTableIAM:
    Effect: Allow
    Action: 
      - dynamodb:PutItem 
      - dynamodb:GetItem
    Resource:
      - arn:aws:dynamodb:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:table/MyCoolTable
```

`resources/dynamo/UsersSubscriptionTable.yml`

```
Resources:
  UsersSubscriptionTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: MyCoolTable
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - AttributeName: email
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: email
          KeyType: HASH
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a huge pain to figure out:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  memorySize: 256
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: us-west-2
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - ${file(resources/iam/UsersSubscriptionTable.yml):UsersSubscriptionTableIAM}

resources:
  Resources:
    UsersSubscriptionTable: ${file(resources/dynamo/UsersSubscriptionTable.yml):UsersSubscriptionTable}
```

Resources shouldn't be an array in this case.

In addition, the iam role statement shouldn't have a resources top-level item in the yml either:

```
UsersSubscriptionTableIAM:
  Effect: Allow
  Action: 
    - dynamodb:PutItem 
    - dynamodb:GetItem
  Resource:
    - arn:aws:dynamodb:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:table/MyCoolTable
```

```
UsersSubscriptionTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: MyCoolTable
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    AttributeDefinitions: 
      - AttributeName: email
        AttributeType: S

    # Specifies the email as the partition key (primary key)
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: email
        KeyType: HASH
```